# Download table to spreadsheet

Tags: uitableview, export, sapui5

I have a sap.m.Table created.  I need to download it to excel.
For that I have followed [this sample](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.ui.export.Spreadsheet/sample/sap.ui.export.sample.table).  Yet the file, although exported, it only contains the titles of each column, rows seem to be kind of known by the file but cells are empty (check image below).

[image]

In my controller I have the following:

```
        onExport : function () {
        var oTable = this.getView().byId("lineItemsList"),
            oRowBinding, aCols, oSettings, oSheet;
            
        oRowBinding = oTable.getBinding("items");
        aCols = this.createColumnConfig();
        
        oSettings = {
            workbook: {
                columns: aCols
                //hierarchyLevel: 'Level'
            },
            dataSource: oRowBinding,
            fileName: "WBS Elements.xlsx"
            //worker: false // We need to disable worker because we are using a MockServer as OData Service
        };

        oSheet = new Spreadsheet(oSettings);
        oSheet.build().finally(function() {
            oSheet.destroy();
        });

    },
```

Then the Column Config in controller:

```
        createColumnConfig: function() {
        var aCols = [];

        aCols.push({
            //label: 'Nivel',
            property: "Level",
            type: EdmType.String,
        });

        aCols.push({
            label: "WBS Element",
            property: "WBS Element",
            type: EdmType.String,
        });

        aCols.push({
            property: "Description",
            type: EdmType.String
        });

        aCols.push({
            property: "Basic Start",
            type: EdmType.Date
        });

        aCols.push({
            property: "Basic Finish",
            type: EdmType.Date
        });

        aCols.push({
            property: "Actual Start",
            type: EdmType.Date,
        });

        aCols.push({
            property: "Actual Finish",
            type: EdmType.Date
        });

        aCols.push({
            property: "Plan PoC%",
            type: EdmType.Number
        });
        
        aCols.push({
            property: "Act PoC%",
            type: EdmType.Number
        });
        
        aCols.push({
            property: "Plan Cost",
            type: EdmType.Number
        });

        aCols.push({
            property: "Actual Cost",
            type: EdmType.Number
        });
        
        aCols.push({
            property: "Budget",
            type: EdmType.Number
        });
        
        aCols.push({
            property: "Curr. Year Budget",
            type: EdmType.Number
        });
        
        aCols.push({
            property: "Status",
            type: EdmType.String
        });
        
        aCols.push({
            property: "Currency",
            type: EdmType.String
        });
        return aCols;
    }
```

And last, the table definition in XML View (took away toolbar definition and other stuff so to focus on relevant):

```
        <semantic:content>
        <Table
            id="lineItemsList"
            width="auto"
            items="{
                path: '/ItProjWbsSet',
                sorter: {
                    path: 'Pspid',
                    descending: false
                }
            }"              
            mode="MultiSelect"
            updateFinished=".onUpdateFinished"
            selectionChange="onSelectionChange"
            noDataText="{i18n>detailLineItemTableNoDataText}"
            busyIndicatorDelay="{detailView>/delay}">               
            <columns>
                <Column demandPopin="false" minScreenWidth="Phone">
                     <Text text="Level"/>
                </Column>
                <Column demandPopin="false" width="12em"  minScreenWidth="Phone">
                     <Text text="WBS Element"/>
                </Column>
                <Column demandPopin="false"  minScreenWidth="Tablet" visible="{= !${device>/system/phone}}">
                     <Text text="Basic Start"/>
                </Column>
                <Column demandPopin="false"  minScreenWidth="Tablet" visible="{= !${device>/system/phone}}">
                     <Text text="Basic Finish"/>
                </Column>   
                <Column demandPopin="false"  minScreenWidth="Tablet" visible="{= !${device>/system/phone}}">
                     <Text text="Actual Start"/>
                </Column>
                <Column demandPopin="false"   minScreenWidth="Tablet" visible="{= !${device>/system/phone}}">
                     <Text text="Actual Finish"/>
                </Column>   
                <Column demandPopin="false"   minScreenWidth="Phone" visible="{= !${device>/system/phone}}">
                     <Text text="Plan PoC%"/>
                </Column>
                <Column demandPopin="false"   minScreenWidth="Phone" visible="{= !${device>/system/phone}}">
                     <Text text="Actual PoC%"/>
                </Column>   
                <Column demandPopin="false"   minScreenWidth="Tablet" visible="{= !${device>/system/phone}}">
                     <Text text="Plan Cost"/>
                </Column>
                <Column demandPopin="false"   minScreenWidth="Tablet" visible="{= !${device>/system/phone}}">
                     <Text text="Act.Cost"/>
                </Column>                   
                <Column demandPopin="false"   minScreenWidth="Tablet" visible="{= !${device>/system/phone}}">
                     <Text text="Budget"/>
                </Column>
                <Column demandPopin="false"   minScreenWidth="Tablet" visible="{= !${device>/system/phone}}">
                     <Text text="Curr.Year Budget"/>
                </Column>
                <Column demandPopin="false"   minScreenWidth="Tablet" visible="{= !${device>/system/phone}}">
                     <Text text="Status"/>
                </Column>   
            </columns>
            <items>
                <ColumnListItem id="listLayout">
                    <cells>
                        <Text text="{Stufe}"/>
                        <ObjectIdentifier
                            title="{Pspid}"
                            text="{Post1}"/>
                        <Text text="{path : 'Pstrt', 
                                     type : 'sap.ui.model.type.Date',
                                     formatOptions: { style : 'short'}}"/>
                        <Text text="{path : 'Pende', 
                                     type : 'sap.ui.model.type.Date',
                                     formatOptions: { style : 'short'}}"/>
                        <Text text="{path : 'Istrt', 
                                     type : 'sap.ui.model.type.Date',
                                     formatOptions: { style : 'short'}}"/>
                        <Text text="{path : 'Iende', 
                                     type : 'sap.ui.model.type.Date',
                                     formatOptions: { style : 'short'}}"/>
                        <ObjectNumber
                            number="{
                                parts:[{path:'PlanCost'},{path:'CurrKey'}],
                                type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Currency',
                                formatOptions: {showMeasure: false}
                            }"
                            unit="{CurrKey}" />
                        <ObjectNumber
                            number="{
                                parts:[{path:'ActualCost'},{path:'CurrKey'}],
                                type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Currency',
                                formatOptions: {showMeasure: false}
                            }"
                            unit="{CurrKey}" />
                        <ObjectNumber
                            number="{
                                parts:[{path:'Budget'},{path:'CurrKey'}],
                                type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Currency',
                                formatOptions: {showMeasure: false}
                            }"
                            unit="{CurrKey}" />
                        <ObjectNumber
                            number="{
                                parts:[{path:'CurrYrBud'},{path:'CurrKey'}],
                                type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Currency',
                                formatOptions: {showMeasure: false}
                            }"
                            unit="{CurrKey}" />
                        <Text text="{Status}"/>                             
                    </cells>                        
                </ColumnListItem>
            </items>
        </Table>
    </semantic:content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use as property name the exact same string as  it is called in your viewModel/oData service.

```
aCols.push({
    label: "Actual Cost"
    property: "ActualCost", // Needs to be property name
    type: EdmType.Number
});
```

For the budget it already matched and therefore a '0' was shown in the excel.